# What does this error mean? (0x80040607-00000000-00000000)

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, exchange, amazon-web-services

One of my colleagues experiences the following error whenever he tries to send e-mails via Outlook. We are using Amazon WorkMail (exchange protocol).

```
Your message did not reach some or all of the intended recipients.

 Subject: Book PDF
 Sent: 24/04/2015 10:50


The following recipient(s) cannot be reached:

 John Smith on 24/04/2015 10:54
 This message could not be sent. Try sending the message again later, or contact your network administrator. Error is [0x80040607-00000000-00000000].
```

I hope someone knows what this error means. Something tells me this is not WorkMail problem, but Outlook/Exchange related error.

Comment: What operating system are you using? What version?
What version of Outlook do you have installed?
When do you get this error message?
Please furnish detailed explanation and we will be glad to help.

Comment: Windows 8. Outlook 2013.

Answer (score 1):

Probably his Outlook setup is wrong. Tell him to check his account setup:

1. make sure @domain.com isn't part of login
2. check other smtp server parameters: server, port, password
3. If that didn't help, troubleshoot using https://support.microsoft.com/kb/813514

(ref: [1](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-outlook/when-i-try-to-send-a-test-mail-it-logs-on-to-the/63b91959-7c6b-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5))

Comment: I will check that. I doubt that is the case, because sometimes sending works, sometimes not. I assume if the login is incorrect, then he would not be able to send emails at all, right?

Comment: @DejanLekic right, if login is wrong, he wouldn't send single email at all. So, if some mails go out, it's not Outlook settings. Maybe look to internet connection and computer settings (some antivirus software messes with the connection?)

Comment: Maybe also check if SMTP authentication is enabled at all. Because when disabled, server still may accept mails for accounts on that server, but not for others.

Answer (score 1):

Translating HRESULT=0x80040607 with Microsoft's [Err utility](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=985):

```
C:\> Err.exe 0x80040607

# for hex 0x80040607 / decimal -2147219961 :
  MAPI_E_NO_RECIPIENTS     mapicode.h     
# 1 matches found for "0x80040607"
```

For MAPI_E_NO_RECIPIENTS [this article](http://2b1mail.com/faqs.php) implies there's a problem with a distribution list, where "Outlook refers to contacts by unique IDs, unavailable to the user". Most articles refer to distribution lists and GetRecipientTable() returning no results.

The function is defined at Microsoft's site [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc815662.aspx), where it is implied that you can proceed (and get an error) before the recipient table is completely available, but because most indications are that no recipients are returned, you might want to check:

- Is a distribution list used? Are all names valid?
- Is "John Smith" a valid lookup? Does it work elsewhere?
- What happens if you use "John Smith's" email address directly?

Since this is a MAPI error (mail programmer's interface) it's appropriate to at least approach Amazon for more information, because they'd have to have written the code to utilize the Microsoft API. It's apparently easy to make mistakes [like this](http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/Development/microsoft.public.win32.programmer.messaging/2004-07/0068.html) but it seems more likely "John Smith"'s account/entry in Exchange is broken (can't look up by name, a related list isn't configured as an email address book, permission issue with list, slow interface to Exchange, etc).

Comment: Note, I am not working in a Windows environment. This answer is interpreted from a windows simulator and web search, and I hope the answer is close enough to find the problem.

Comment: I am exclusively Linux user myself. I asked the question because my colleagues who use Outlook have big problems...